# Show the norm map is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $K/F$ be an extension of finite field. Show that the norm map $N_{K/F}$ is surjective.

Here is what I have so far:

Since $F$ is a finite field and $K/F$ is a finite extension of degree $n$, so $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)=\langle\sigma\rangle$, where $\sigma(a)= a^{q}$ with $q=p^{m}=|F|$. In addition, by primitive element theorem, $K=F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$.

We want to show $N_{K/F}(\alpha)$ generates $F$. By the definition of norm, we have $$N_{K/F}(\alpha)=\alpha^{1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}}$$ and since $(1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1})(q-1)=q^n-1$, we have the order of $N_{K/F}(\alpha)$ is divided by $q-1$.

But I want to show $o(N_{K/F}(\alpha))=q-1$ in order to conclude surjectivity. So any hint for how to proceed? Any other methods are also perferred.

Comment: How could the order be any larger? Kudos for showing your work.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Yeah. I'm stucking here. I believe it couldn't be larger, but I can't see it.

Comment: Actually, don't we actually have the opposite? If $a$ is an element of a group and $a^n = 1$, then I know that the order of $a$ divides $n$. But I don't get the reverse. [By the way, it's best to use `\cdots` when writing things like $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$.]

Comment: Another way to see this is to consider the kernel of the norm map. What can you say about an element in the kernel? How big can the kernel be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you have a lot of the right stuff written down. Let's take $\alpha$ to be a generator for the cyclic [see Lemma 1.6 [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf) for a proof] group $K^*$, so $\alpha$ has order $q^n - 1$. Then, as you say, its norm is
\[
N_{K/F}(\alpha) = \alpha^{1 + q + \cdots + q^{n - 1}} \in F^*.
\]
This norm generates $F^*$ because its order is precisely $q - 1$. This is just group theory: if an element $x$ in a group has order $mk$ then $x^m$ has order $k$.

You could also focus on the size of the kernel, as [Mike B suggests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143711/show-the-norm-map-is-surjective/143719#comment331182_143711). As [Brandon points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143711/show-the-norm-map-is-surjective#comment331209_143719), these are the roots of a certain polynomial, which gives you an upper bound. And there is an obvious lower bound.

A very useful generalization of this is [Hilbert's Theorem 90](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Theorem_90).

Comment: Elements of the kernel are roots of $x^{1+q+\dots+q^{n-1}}-1$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter Ah, I think it follows from facts about cyclic groups as well, but I like your way even better.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $N_{K/F}(\alpha) \in K^{\rm{Gal}(K/F)}= F$.